# Eloquent get a table from intermediate table

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have 3 table given below

```
Products
+id
+Name

ProductAttributes
+id
+name
+value
+product_id
+attribute_group_id


AttributeGroups
+id
+name


relation
---------
Product hasmany ProductAtrribute

ProductAtrributes belongsTo Products

ProductAtrributes belongsTo AttributeGroups
```

I want to eager load product and attribute groups and attribute group with its attribute

Comment: try $product = `Product::with('productAtrributes', 'productAtrributes.attributeGroups')->find(1);` assuming you have `productAtrributes` and `attributeGroups` are name of relation

Comment: @rkj thanks, this i already figured out. 
But i want the product to  list its attributes groups first, then get the attributes that belong to group

Comment: you have no relation between `Product` and `AttributeGroups` then how can you fetch it.

Comment: if you add `product_id` in `AttributeGroups` and `attribute_group_id` in `ProductAtrribute` then you can

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [`BelongsToMany`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many) relationship:

```php
class Product extends Model {
    public function attributeGroups() {
        return $this->belongsToMany(AttributeGroup::class, 'product_attributes')
            ->withPivot('name', 'value');
    }
}

$product = Product::find(1);
foreach($product->attributeGroups as $attributeGroup) {
    // $attributeGroup->name
    // $attributeGroup->pivot->value
}
```

Comment: Can you please give feedback on the answer?